# Laravel bulk mail queue rendering

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis

I have to send bulk email to more than 50k email using Laravel queue with Redis.

Isn't the view rendered and serialised along with data and stored in the queue.
Then this will be a problem as memory cannot handle all the data for 50k emails.

What i am thinking is to store the rendered view seperatly in db and before sending 
re-render with correct data. This way we can reduce the size of queued item.

Is this possible this way. Or is there any other way?

Comment: You are planning to send to all 50k users in one job, or will you be create a job for each email (i.e. 50k jobs)?

Comment: probable divide it and send for 10k in one go

Comment: Why wouldn't you just send each email separately and let the queue handle the sending of each email? You would be 50k rows in the queue but you won't have memory issues, and if the queue stops, you can continue where you left off...

Comment: @NirajShah Sorry i didn't get you. What i understand from what you told me is that you want to push all 50k jobs to queue at one time? Then we make the same problem which i am trying to solve.

Kindly correct me if i misunderstood you.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the queue does not store the rendered emails in the DB. So pushing 50k rows to the queue shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @NirajShah run the queue process on production settings on a test machine and Redis reports it takes only 900MB when all jobs is queued, this is ok for now.

Comment: @NirajShah i made a mistake when is was testing, the view is actually serialised and one serialised object is ~ 246KB, which makes equates to 9+ GB if all jobs are pushed at once.

Comment: Big difference between 900 MB and 9 GB! Does the application still work when sending out the emails or are you getting memory issues?